How to identify upstream/downstream flow of streams with respect to a point?
I have water streams data and point data of certain treatment plants along those streams (two separate files). I need to know whether the stream is upstream or downstream from each of those treatment sites? - Basically, I need to know which side of the treatment site is upstream and which is downstream since I will compare houses on either sides of a treatment plant. I have state fdr.TIF data, my streams data does not have any flow direction data. The red points are the "problem areas" and green stars are the "treatment sites" built near the streams (in green). So I need to know the upstream/downstream of these streams with respect to those green stars.
I tried getting DEM data to create contour lines but the my DEM data has lowest range as low as -800 which I have been told might be incorrect. I tried downloading it from https://apps.nationalmap.gov/downloader/#/ for entire state, which is taking forever to download and takes up 200+GB memory on my system. Is there an efficient way to do this? My stream data does not have any indicators to determine flow/direction, etc.


Hi, this video might help. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HA7e0nsyDvA

Can you explain by editing your question what you mean by the stream is u/s or d/s of the treatment site? Are you asking if you want to know if ALL polylines that make up the river network are u/s of a site? What about the d/s direction, do you consider going d/s then UP another tributary a d/s direction. It is unclear what you are asking. Edit your question and add a sketch of what you have and what you want.

Hi @Hornbydd, I have edited my question. Thank you for the feedback.

Again a little bit unclear but it sounds like you want to create a reach u/s and d/s of the site point. Have a look at RivEX, a tool designed in ArcPro to process river networks and solve problems such as yours. Have a look at the reach tools is that what you were after, if not I suggest you add an image to your question.

Assuming your streams are hydrologically correct (pointing in the direction of flow and all nodes were connected) you could convert those to a network and trace up and down of those points.  It looks like you will need a standard license at least.  Start here and re-post with new and specific issues.  https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/utility-networks/trace.htm

@GBG My streams data do not have flow direction. I have a separate FDR.TIF file but the streams themselves are missing flow direction data.

@Hornbydd I have added an image and updated the question, hope this helps.

So are you saying for each green star (treatment works) you want to say if the red points are u/s or d/s of it?

@Hornbydd no I have houses point data, I want to check whether they are u/s d/s wrt the green points. the red ones are problem locations. I was able to get upstream watershed area using watershed tool (now I have FDR/Flow Acc rasters as well) but I am still unable to get a defined upstream line or downstream line for all points at once.
